# Google's Static Maps not Rendering on Page

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I am having a very hard time to make the image generated by Google's Maps renders inside my html image tags in my website.

I am enconding the user data (address, city, state) with php urlencode() and I am using the php htmlentitites() in the final URL. The Google's map image does not render in the page, but if I open img src by the browser source inspector code and click on it, the map renders ok in a new window, when URL is not placed as img src, but as the main URL in the browser.

Look at my code:

```
<?php
$State = urlencode($data['record']['field_42']);
$City = urlencode($data['record']['field_43']);
$Address = urlencode($data['record']['field_44']);
$Image_map = htmlentities("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=$Address,$City,$State&size=570x400&key=&sensor=false&maptype=hybrid");
?>

<img src="<?php echo $Image_map; ?>" alt="Location" height="400" width="570">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Quick Example section of the static maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example) I see that spaces in the query string have to be encoded, e.g. as `+`.

Assuming that your `$Address` variable can contain spaces, you'll need to ensure that you properly encode them before placing them inside your `img`'s `src`. The difference from the browser bar could be that there the browser takes care of the encoding for you, but inside an html element's attribute it doesn't.